# How to lazy load multiple components at a same time in React

Tags: reactjs, lazy-evaluation

```
const {A, B, C, D} = React.lazy(() => import("../test"));
```

Destructuring multiple components from one folder and applying lazy to all the components? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

What you have described specifically is not possible.

It is in theory possible to destructure an import, but you wouldn't be able to interact with it outside of the closure passed to `lazy` because it isn't available yet. Remember, [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) are not a function of React, but the browser. You can destructure a dynamically imported module, but to do so would require using `await`.

```
const {A, B} = await import('your/module');
```

In the context of React this would halt all execution in the file, which obviously is not what we want.

In order for it behave properly, you would need to destructure within the `lazy` callback.

I have not been able to test this, but in theory it should work:

```
const ComponentA = React.lazy(() => {
    const {A} = await import("../test");
    return A
})

const ComponentB = React.lazy(() => {
    const {B} = await import("../test");
    return B
})
```